# How to attach replacement beams to column when repairing pergola

Tags: beam, pergola, column

I'm planning to replace some rotten beams on a free-standing pergola.  What is the best way to attach them to the top of the existing columns? The columns are hollow squares made of 3/4" boards with a flat cap (made of a 1/2" board with flashing). The beams are 1 1/2" thick.  I can't tell how they're currently attached - maybe just toed in, which doesn't seem very sturdy to me.  I'm thinking of using [Simpson Z-Max hurricane ties](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-Z-MAX-18-Gauge-Galvanized-Hurricane-Tie-H2-5AZ/100275721), but is there a better way that will look nicer?

[image: Photo of area between beams on top of column]
[image: Side photo of where 2 beams and a rafter meet on top of column]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Simpson's Outdoor Accents Product Line. [Catalog here](https://www.strongtie.com/products/go/connectors/outdooraccents/mission-collection)

[image]
[image]